# converting 20 amp outlet to 15 amp

Tags: electrical

n my garage is an receptacle that looks like a 20Amp outlet (It has one horizontal and one T-shaped slot on the top and a grounding slot below).  I do not have any need for this kind of receptacle and would like to change it to a 15-amp duplex.  When I opened the outlet box, though, there are THREE wires connected to the receptacle: a red, a white and a black.  I am not sure why there is a third wire - can someone help me understand the purpose of that?  Does this mean I cannot wire in a regular 15-amp duplex, which normally only has a white and a black.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Pictures would help, and where do you live in the world? If you're in the USA then this sounds like a 240v outlet. You can still convert it to a "normal" 15A duplex relatively easily but some photos would help confirm next steps.

Comment: Did you notice if the tab was broken off between the black and red?  Do you know if any other outlets/receptacles are on this circuit?  There is a very good chance this receptacle is powered by two single breakers or one dual breaker.

Comment: Is this a single receptacle which only allows one plug to be connected, or a duplex receptacle with two outlets?

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Oddly enough, the code allows for 20 amp and 15 amp outlets to be interchangeable on either 15 amp (14 ga. wire) or 20 amp (12 ga wire).  In other words, you can put a 15amp outlet on a 20 amp circuit and vice versa.   Like @HotLicks asked...why are you wanting to change it?.....EDIT:  Uh Oh, It might be a 240v outlet, maybe leftover from a high wattage heater, or A/C unit.  Pics are critical.  All outlets are configured so you can't plug something in that isn't correct for the voltage and amperage supplied.  Is the T-shaped portion on the right or the left with the ground under them?

Comment: 20A sockets accept 15A plugs, so you should be all set.  The neutral is a T... Are you saying the hot slot is sideways? Is it sideways *on both sockets*?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the existing receptacle? What kind of breaker is it currently connected to?

Answer (score 3):

That's a 240V 6-20 outlet.

`It has one horizontal and one T-shaped slot`

The 5-20 has one **vertical** and one T-shaped, so this is definitely a 240V outlet.

Might come in handy for a car charger.

It can be converted to a 120V outlet, with some work in the breaker box feeding it and the outlet box. There are multiple options for that, actually - the easiest would be to make it a 5-20 MWBC with two outlets on one dual breaker, with the tab between the hots broken off. There's no need to make it a 5-15, as 5-15 plugs will plug into that configuration (they don't plug into the 6-20 or 6-15 outlets by design, and that's a good thing, as those supply twice the voltage they expect.)

Comment: The three wires are still puzzling though, since a 6-20 doesn't use a neutral.

Comment: The lack of a 4th, green or bare, unless in metal conduit, is also concerning. pictures would certainly help.